Exchange MTU not supported when connecting to a BLE device from Raspberry
I have a Raspberry Pi 5 device, with Raspbian (Debian Bookworm). I bought a Chinese led strip, with a Bluetooth controller on it, and I would like to connect to it from the Pi. I'm using bluez 5.66, and with bluetoothctl, I can discover the device, and can connect to it, but after a few seconds it is disconnected. With btmon, I can see the logs, and I see that my Pi is trying to negotiate the mtu size, but the other device says it is not supported. After 2 tries, the remote device sends a disconnect request.
What else can I do to successfully connect to the device and be able to control it from my Raspberry?
I can connect this device with nrfConnect Android app, reading services and characteristics, but in Linux, I cannot. I see that the Raspberry is trying to request mtu size 256 and 517. I tried to change this to start with 23 (the default minimum), but I could not find anything to change this setting.
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 36                                                                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 3986.939818
        LE Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
        Flags: 0x00000008
          Connection Locally Initiated
        Data length: 23
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
        Appearance: Remote Control (0x0180)
        Name (complete): BJ_LED_M
@ RAW Open: btmon (privileged) version 2.22                                                                                              {0x0003} 3986.939936
@ RAW Close: btmon                                                                                                                       {0x0003} 3986.939939
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                                                      #310 [hci0] 3986.958372
        Handle: 64 Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                             #311 [hci0] 3986.958668
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                                            #312 [hci0] 3986.958826
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 256
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                                             #313 [hci0] 3987.058225
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64 Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
        Features: 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
< ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                                            #314 [hci0] 3987.058442
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 517
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                                                #315 [hci0] 3987.106843
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 64 Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
        Count: 2
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                            #316 [hci0] 3987.155455
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Exchange MTU Request (0x02)
        Handle: 0x0000
        Error: Request Not Supported (0x06)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                                                                            #317 [hci0] 3987.204202
      ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4
        Exchange MTU Request (0x02)
        Handle: 0x0000
        Error: Request Not Supported (0x06)
@ MGMT Command: Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7                                                                                        {0x0001} [hci0] 3999.297866
        LE Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                                                        #318 [hci0] 3999.297915
        Handle: 64 Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
        Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection (0x13)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                                             #319 [hci0] 3999.298214
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                                        #320 [hci0] 3999.343600
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 64 Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                                                                                   {0x0001} [hci0] 3999.343613
      Disconnect (0x0014) plen 7
        Status: Success (0x00)
        LE Address: FF:10:10:81:F8:F4 (OUI FF-10-10)


Maybe the problem isn't the MTU setting but the Human Interface Device requirements. The server is an HID device which must be paired with security level 2 or 3 for encryption. Try pairing immediately after connection.
